# How to set permission for Azure Active directory application in Azure DataLake Store using powershell commands

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake

[image]

Hi,

I am trying to set the AAD(Azure Active Directory) application permission(read/write/execute & other settings) in ADLS(Azure DataLakeStore) using powershell commands.

I tried using below powershell command:

> Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -AccountName "adls" -Path /
>   -AceType User -Id (Get-AzureRmADApplication -ApplicationId  490eee0-2ee1-51ee-88er-0f53aerer7b).ApplicationId -Permissions All

**But this command sets/displays the ApplicationId under "Access" properties in ADLS with only read/write/execute access. But this setting are not correct as I perform Manual steps of Service Authentication in ADLS.**

[image]

Is there any other way to set permissions of AAD application in ADLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `User` of `Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry` commands should be the object ID of the AzureActive Directory user, group, or **service principal** for which to modify an ACE.

You can refer the command below to assign the permission:

```
Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -AccountName "accountName" -Path / -AceType User -Id
(Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName "{applicationId}").Id -Permissions All
```

More detail about this command, you can refer link below:

[Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datalakestore/set-azurermdatalakestoreitemaclentry?view=azurermps-4.2.0#optional-parameters)

Comment: Hi Fei Xue, the above command sets permission to ADLS at root level. The AAD Application permission is not displayed for child folders. How do I set permissions for root and its child folder using PowerShell?

Comment: @Amruta To grant the permission which could inherit by children, we need to grant the **Default ACLs** instead of **Access ACLs**. To grant the **Default ACLs**, please add the `Default` parameter in the command. More detail about the permissions in Azure Data Lake, please refer the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control).

Comment: Thank you so much Fei Xue for reply..This resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the ObjectId (not the application id) as the Id parameter to `Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry`

```
Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemAclEntry -AccountName "adls" -Path / -AceType User -Id (Get-AzureRmADApplication -ApplicationId 490eee0-2ee1-51ee-88er-0f53aerer7b).Id -Permissions All
```

Comment: (Get-AzureRmADApplication -ApplicationId 490eee0-2ee1-51ee-88er-0f53aerer7b).ObjectId.. This returns a empty value..If I try above answer with only (Get-AzureRmADApplication -ApplicationId 490eee0-2ee1-51ee-88er-0f53aerer7b).Id solved the issue. Well thank you for your reply..

Comment: Doh..yes indeed the property name is not ObjectId but Id. Thanks for confirming. I've changed the response to reflect. Please mark as answer for future reference.